# User friendly site structure

Tags: url, structure, forum, user-friendly

### Introduction

I am trying to learn to create websites that aren't just static, and this is probably a 'noob' question but I can't seem to find an answer anywhere.

### What I want to achieve

Let's say I want to make a forum/social media type website, I want url structure like this:

`home:        www.website.com`

`userpage:    www.website.com/user/username`

`post:        www.website.com/post/postid`

### What I can make right now

I've only played around in PHP and nothing like ASP.net but all I can do at the moment is this:

`home:        www.website.com`

`userpage:    www.website.com/user/?user=username`

`post:        www.website.com/post/?post=postid`

How can I create site structure without the `?var=id` like you see on almost every website?

Examples:

www.reddit.com/r/subreddit

www.medium.com/user/post

Answer (score 0):

You should learn to make RESTful apis ([REST wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer))

> REST works almost exactly like a website in a browser. A resource is
>   exposed to a program via a URL. The program can access that URL and
>   receive data about the resource, not unlike when you type in a URL to
>   your browser and get a web page back.

*Quote from: http://www.mashery.com/blog/what-restful-api*